# Ie filter:alpha(opacity) black border

Tags: internet-explorer

Having an issue where filter: alpha(opacity) is adding black jaggys around the edge of my images.

Interestingly not around the image itself but around the edges of its transparency (it is a transparent PNG).

But this is also happening on text I have absolutly positioned.

Any help would be very appretiated!

It looks fine in other browsers, obviously not using filter:

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This man here has an explanation of the problem, as well as a workaround:

Blog post:

http://yordanstoev.com/blog/2009/05/22/png-transparency-plus-opacity-internet-explorer-8-bug/

Workaround:

http://yordanstoev.com/blog/showroom/ie8bug/working.html

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who ever finds this.

Result I eventually found on MSDN is it's possible using MS propreity CSS, but its completely impractical.

Comment: what is the link on MSDN where you found this? Bing/Google failed me.