# Black border on Google Map?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps

I have some problems with in Internet Explorer when I use infoboxes with a shadow. It works fine in FF and Chrome, but not in IE8. Help is preciated! Thanks!

[image: Infobox on Google Map]

Comment: Is this available somewhere so that we can inspect it

Comment: I have just removed it and changed to a infobox without any shadow, but I would really like to solve this problem. It seems like it's a common problem when searching about it, but not any solution??

Comment: I can show you millions of infoWindows where the issue didn't occur in IE8, so we need something to isolate the problem-

Comment: I have no problem with infoWindow, I'm using infoBoxes. This is two different things, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infobox sets opacity, so if you are attempting to use a shadow with alpha-transparency, it will fail in IE. IE cannot cope with transparency and opacity together.

[Ie filter:alpha(opacity) black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904480/ie-filteralphaopacity-black-border) may help.

Comment: Thanks, I have to test this as soon as possible. Should I place this in the CSS file?